# Replace multiple substrings in PHP without going over old ones

Tags: php

When trying to use PHP's str_replace function to replace multiple substrings, is there a way to get it to ignore the strings it's just replaced?

For example, when executing the following code block, it replaces the "o" in "<strong>" from the first replacement.

```
$str="Hello world.";
$old=array("e","o");
$new=array("<strong>e</strong>","<strong>o</strong>");

echo str_replace($old,$new,$str);
```

The actual output:

```
// "H<str<strong>o</strong>ng>e</str<strong>o</strong>ng>ll<strong>o</strong> w<strong>o</strong>rld."
```

The expected output:

```
// "H<strong>e</strong>ll<strong>o</strong> w<strong>o</strong>rld."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

From the PHP manual:

> The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for - can't believe I missed it in the docs!

Answer (score 1):

The alternative solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
echo preg_replace("/(e|o)/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
// H<strong>e</strong>ll<strong>o</strong> w<strong>o</strong>rld.
```